# White inactive bottom space on CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, coordinator-layout

I have the xml-file with CoordinatorLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
            <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp">
                    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                        app:tabBackground="@drawable/my_tab_item_bg_selector"
                        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                        app:tabGravity="fill"
                        app:tabMode="fixed"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And I have another xml-file which I put on coordinator layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollData"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDataDispatchContacts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutFullTableDispatchContacts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_block_background">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLinearLayoutDispatchContacts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I catching bug of empty space, which covers the part of my window and not clickable. This is on screenshot below:
[unclickable inactive bottom space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RT6pG.png)
I noticed that when I deleting app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" from my ViewPager, the bug disappears. But my names of tabs disappear too. I think it creates some invisible toolbar or something like that.

Comment: isn't that white space the area of 'layoutBottom' in your case?

Comment: no, I've changed code, removed unnecessary

Comment: I found some stupid solution.

Comment: I've removed app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" from ViewPager and NestedScrollView, replaced android:layout_height="wrap_content" in AppBarLayout and TabLayout with android:layout_height="45dp" and added android:layout_marginTop="45dp" to ViewPager. Not best solution but it works. Problem was really in appbar_scrolling_view_behavior. It added empty bottom space. I don't even care why.

Comment: You added appbar_scrolling_view_behavior in both ViewPager and NestedScrollView which caused the issue, it should be added in the direct child of CoordinatorLayout only, which in your case is ViewPager. NestedScrollView is part of sub layout.

Comment: I tried to remove it from NestedScrollView too. There was the same result.

Comment: I have created the layout using your code and it would work fine by setting height of CoordinatorLayout to match_parent. Check this and let me know.

Comment: It works. That's really strange. Thank's.

Comment: I am posting it as answer , accept it so it would be helpful for others as well who might be having same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As CoordinatorLayout is working as parent of subviews so, to occupy full screen you need to set the height to match parent  instead of wrap_content like this:

> android:layout_height="match_parent"

and it would work fine.